# Regular Expression to replace "[" and "]"

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular experssion for java to replace the "[" and the "]" . the compiler give error because [ is the syntax of regex. what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to escape the special characters - `\[` and `\]`. This applies to all special characters too.

Comment: `]` doesn't need to be escaped in this case, only inside a character class.

Comment: And of course the usual double escaping that stems from the use of Java's strings applies: `"\\[\\]"`

Answer (score 1):

backslashes!  for any character that has a special meaning, you preface it with a backslash to match the literal character.

```
Pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\]");
```

(pay attention that because it's java, you need two backslashes to equate to one backslash char).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
String s = ...
s = s.replaceAll("\\[|]", "");
```

or:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[[\\]]", "");
```

or a non-regex replacement (so no escaping needed):

```
s = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

An explanation of the regexes (the first 2 examples):

### 1: `\\[|]`

```
\\[    # match `[`
|      # OR
]      # match ']'
```

### 2: `[[\\]]`

```
[      # start character class
  [    # match '[', or
  \\]  # match ']'
]      # end character class
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can escape special characters with backslashes

\[

or

\]